# onSelect event in JQuery Datepicker doesn't seem to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This is probably just a simple error, but I spent the last 3 hours trying to figure it out - without success.

What I would like to do eventually is to use the date entered and compare it with a deadline date to say whether the submission is too late. At the moment, however, for simplifying purposes, I would just like it to tell me that the date has changed, but with no success. Where am I going wrong here?

```
$("#id_submission_date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $("#late_submission_warning").text("Date selected");
    }
 });
```

Here is the (shortened) HTML from the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>  Feedback for Student, Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/static/css/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .sidebar-nav{
            padding: 9px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
...
</nav>

<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='...' />

<div class="container">

    <h1>European Law (2013/2014): Essay</h1>
    <h2>Test Student</h2>
     ...

    <label for="submission_date">Submission Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="id_submission_date" name="submission_date" type="text" value="13/04/2015" />

    <select class="form-control" id="id_category_mark_2" name="category_mark_2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="39">0 - 39 %</option>
        <option value="49">40 - 49 %</option>
        <option value="59">50 - 59 %</option>
        <option value="69">60 - 69 %</option>
        <option value="79">70 - 79 %</option>
        <option value="80">80 or more</option>
    </select>

    <div id="late_submission_warning"></div>

    <h4>General Comments</h4>
    <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="id_comments" name="comments" rows="10">
    </textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    $("#sortable_table").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]]
        }); 
    } 
); 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#id_submission_date").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            console.log(dateText);
        }
    });

    $("#category_2").qtip({
        content: {
            text: '80+ very full and perceptive awareness of issues, with original critical and analytical assessment of the issues and an excellent grasp of their wider significance.<br />70+ full and perceptive awareness of issues and a clear grasp of their wider significance.<br />60 - 69 adequate awareness of issues and a serious understanding of their wider significance.<br />50 - 59 some awareness of issues and their wider significance.<br />40 - 49 limited awareness of issues and their wider significance.<br />Below 40 very limited awareness of issues and of their wider significance.'
            }
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post html as well

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that there is an issue somewhere with your JavaScript and you will have to see for the console messages to see what is going wrong.

Anyhow I would want to see the complete HTML and code before making any comments or a complete solution. But as per your request to keep things simple and see that date changed is properly captured, we have to follow the following approach.

```
     $("#id_submission_date").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
         console.log(dateText);
        }
     });
```

Here the "dateText" should contain the desired selected date. Check your browser console for that. If however there is an error, the proper error will be displayed.

**Once you get the appropriate date, you can do the comparisons.**

Incase of error, kindly post the error message here and we can discuss more.

Comment: I have used the code you specified, but nothing whatsoever appears in the Console - neither in Chromium nor in Firebug. 

I could post the full HTML code, but it's a Django page, and it's quite long and complex. Everything else works perfectly fine, so I thought the error must lie with the new code.

Comment: If the console.log() is not printing anything on the screen, this implies that the code never goes to the console. This can mean that something is going wrong before the datepicker code is executed and compiler never gets to this point.

Comment: Strangely, the datepicker itself gets displayed when I click on the field. If there is an error in the code, it would normally not do that, would it?